# Reverse engineering PS2 Naruto 3D Model Format

Tags: game-hacking, code-modeling

As a personal project, I've been trying to reverse engineer the model for a Naruto PS2 game, but to no success in trying to visualize vertex data and faces with Model Ressearcher, and the .OBJ extraction using PCSX2 didn't work either, since it uses culling. Could you guys please help me out? thanks in advance.

Samples: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AIwxQT7cg9l2PO1N_0zm1rXhUpyp1y0_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link is down

Comment: link fixed, sorry for that.

Comment: I tried with different apps like MDL exporter. Not luck